# Is it possible to create lock screen function?

Tags: android

I am currently doing my final year project which is developing an anti-theft application, my idea is to lock the phone screen with password once the phone is stolen so that the theft will not be able to access anything in the phone unless he has the correct password. Is it possible to create this lock screen function? Can anyone give me some guidance or tutorials as I am quite new in Android programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your minimum supported OS is 2.2 (Froyo, API 8) then you can use the [DevicePolicyManager lockNow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29) method.

If you want to know more about the DevicePolicyManager interface, try looking at the DeviceAdminSample in the ApiDemos sample code.  The Android SDK comes with all the samples so you can easily add the ApiDemos as an Eclipse project and run it in the simulator.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but if the screen is locked can any services such as receiving SMS, triggering front camera be done?

Comment: You can receive SMS, but I'm pretty sure you can't use the Camera while the screen is locked